# .NET UserControl Bootstrap jQuery Menu Active Selected

Tags: jquery, .net, twitter-bootstrap, user-controls, nav

I'd like to know if there's a better way to keep a secondary menu list item active. I have a UserControl which contains a list item menu:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li id="menu-overview">overview</li>
    <li id="menu-portfolio" class="active">portfolio</li>
    <li id="menu-performance">performance</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see "portfolio" is active. Then below I remove the active and make "overview" active:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".nav li").removeClass("active");//this will remove the active class from  
        // previously active menu item 
        $('#menu-overview').addClass('active');
    });
```

The thing is I have to include the above script on each page that has the menu and change the menu item to which ever should be active.

Isn't there a better way I can include this all in the UserControl or perhaps a master page if needs be.

**EDITED: Further on...**

Eventually went with this.

In the stylesheet:

```
<style>
  body form[action="overview"] #main-menu li.active1, 
  body form[action="portfolio"] #main-menu li.active2, 
  body form[action="performance"] #main-menu li.active3, 
    {
       border-bottom: 1px solid white;
       background-color: white;
    }
</style>
```

The HTML something like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-menu">                        
  <li class="active1">overview</li>
  <li class="active2">portfolio</li>
  <li class="active3">performance</li>
</ul>
```

And a hover...

```
<style>
  ul#main-menu li:hover 
     {
       background: red;
       padding-bottom: 16px;
     }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this in my projects by either

**A)**

On the click event of a menu option, save the option ID in a session object and always add `class="active"` to the stored option at Page_Load.

**B)**

Make the second part of the `id="menu-xxx"` a substring of your url structure. For example, parse http://www.example.com/example/overview for the word after the last `/` and add `class="active"` to the matching `li` element.

Probably not the best solutions, but something I have used in similar situations.

Comment: Oh my bad, when I read your answer again now it's pretty much what we're doing. @Magnus